# Shadowbox is not Defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, shadowbox

Alright, so, I am using Shadowbox, which is a jQuery Lightbox (per se), and according to Firebug, it may be breaking my code.

This is the exact error:

> Error: Shadowbox is not defined Line: 19

This is my code in my JavaScript/jQuery file.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("a img").hover(function() {
        jQuery(this).stop().animate({opacity: "0.75"}, 'slow');
    },
    function() {
        jQuery(this).stop().animate({opacity: "1"}, 'slow');
    });
    if ( jQuery('.slider')[0] ) (
        jQuery(".slider").slideshow({
            width      : 900,
            height     : 150,
            transition : 'SquareRandom',
            navigation : false,
            selector : false,
            timer : false,
            control : false,
        })
    );
    Shadowbox.init();
});
```

What is going on here!
Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you :)

Comment: It seems the page doesn't have Shadowbox js reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that Shadowbox was not loaded. In your `<head>` tag, make sure you have something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Shadowbox.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have shadowbox included to page, but the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
shadowbox({
    continuous: true,
    counterType:"skip",
});
```

Source: https://github.com/mjackson/shadowbox/issues/45

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shadowbox/shadowbox.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="shadowbox/shadowbox.js"> Shadowbox.init({    language:   "pl",    enableKeys:   "true", continuous: true,   counterType:"skip",}); </script>
```

My solution is simple.. Just add all in one line.